# At the beginning of DS9 Season 6, under what justification did the Dominion occupy DS9?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-dominion

At the beginning of DS9 Season 6, the Dominion (including the Jem Ha'dar and the Cardassians) took DS9. At this time Bajor was neutral and in a non-aggression treaty with the Dominion.

How was this justified? Given Kira's and Odo's (reluctant) initial acceptance of this occupation and willingness to collaborate with it, it seemed that this occupation was legitimate. How could it be? Shouldn't Bajor control the station? As a neutral power, doesn't giving access to an important base violate the neutrality? At best, the Dominion could only be a guest in the station, but it looks like they are *running* the station.

Comment: Presumably, it was an explicit condition of the non-aggression treaty.

Answer (score 3):

It essentially boils down to DS9 being a former Federation outpost, and being the most strategically important location in the entire war. DS9 is not solely owned and operated by Bajor, it was "given" to Bajor, but the Federation essentially controlled it. Once the war started DS9 essentially controls the wormhole between the Gamma Quadrant and the Beta Quadrant, and while the Federation holds it, they can deny Dominion reinforcement, and while the Dominion holds it they can theoretically reinforce as much as they want.

It's also important to note that Bajor is neutral, not because they are impartial, but because they know they will lose, so it is not an equal standing neutrality, the Dominion can essentially force anything they want on Bajor in the name of peace, and Bajor will not break its neutrality.

In World War II, Hitler used similar tactics in Europe to increase Germany's land holdings, by taking what he wanted, and knowing that the powers that be, did not want to start a war with him.

Comment: Uh. Godwin's law on first answer...

Comment: I seem to remember Gul Dukat having a throw away line at some point about reclaiming all Cardassian territory, including DSN.

Comment: @Xantec yes i believe DS9 was built by the cardassian's so it would be logical for them to want to "reclaim" their own territory.

Answer (score 0):

**At the beginning of DS9 Season 6, under what justification did the Dominion occupy DS9?**

The short answer is: **It was taken by force.**

The Dominion had not justification or right of any kind to takeover and hold Deep Space 9 (Terak Nor).  Captain Sisko chose to withdraw all Federation personnel to prevent the station from being destroyed by the Dominion.

The Dominion wanted the station because it was next to the wormhole.  They needed access to it so they could move supplies, troops, ships, etc... from their home world in the Gamma Quadrant.

The other component to this is Gul Dukat and his massive ego.  Dukat made a speech wherein he stated all Cardassian property would be returned to Cardassian control.  Really, Dukat (played by Mark Alaimo) didn't really want to end the occupation of Bajor.